# Custom edge styles - cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I know cytoscape.js has lots of edge styles, but is there a way to set the triangle, diamond, circle, square etc as the edge style?

If it is not possible, then is it possible to write extensions to do that?  If yes, are there any examples of how to write such extension?

Here are examples:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example for this? (I don't know what a square edge would look like?)

Comment: Is [this](https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/edge-arrows/) what you are searching for?

Comment: @StephanT.  Thanks, Just added an example.  The square could be triangle, circle, diamond etc, could be solid, or hollow

Comment: Well I know of 3 kinds of edge lines, solid, dotted and dashed. The latter two options are actively discouraged due to higher cost for drawing.

Comment: If you'd like to contribute to cytoscape.js and do some work for this feature, please refer to [this](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js#contributing-to-cytoscapejs) document. Otherwise, you could also add a feature request on the projects GitHub page (New Issue with a Issue Type "Feature Request")

Comment: thanks, is there any document on how to get this done as extension?

Comment: The link I provided takes you to [CONTRIBUTING.md](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/unstable/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md), there you can read about the process of either submitting an issue (-> possibility for a future feature/extension) or contributing to the project (there is also a first time contributer document)

Comment: Thanks!  reading it now